# Two labels in the middle of center

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I want to place two labels in the middle of the center of a window. I get it working with 1 label and the following code:

Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/scr1g6u0f.png

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame contentPane = new JFrame();
    contentPane.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 

    JLabel label = new JLabel("center1");
    centerPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

    contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now I want another label next to the first label. I tried to use a flowlabel, but they are placed at the top of the BorderLayout.CENTER

Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/scr2a3u26.png

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame contentPane = new JFrame();
    contentPane.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("center1");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("center2");

    JPanel flowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    flowPanel.add(label1);
    flowPanel.add(label2);

    centerPanel.add(flowPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

    contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a GridBagLayout without constraints:

```
   JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 

   JLabel label1 = new JLabel("center1");
   JLabel label2 = new JLabel("center2");

   JPanel flowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
   flowPanel.add(label1);
   flowPanel.add(label2);

   centerPanel.add(flowPanel);
```

Comment: @NoobieNoob: because BorderLayout will take the CENTER JPanel, the one you call flowPanel, and have it fill the container JPanel, called centerPanel. The JLabels will naturally float to the top of the flowlayout using JPanel. The GridBagLayout, if used without constraints won't have the flowPanel fill the centerPanel.